# Problema com variável de session

Tags: php, javascript, html, session, checkbox

No meu site, tenho uma parte do código onde deve ser mostrada duas opções de checkbox para o caso data de check-in com diferença maior ou igual a 72 horas (ou 3 dias) em relação ao dia de hoje.

```
<?php
$difdias = (1/86400)*(strtotime($_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio'])-strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));
if(($_REQUEST['idHotel'] == '373443') && ($difdias >= 3)) {
echo "<tr><td><div id='chkDolars' name='valueDolars' class='checkbox chkSelecionado' style='margin-bottom: 10px'><span class='ph03_105'></span></div><div id='chkReais' name='valueReais' class='checkbox' style='margin-bottom: 10px'><span class='ph03_103'></span></div></td>";
echo "<td><div id='msgReais'><span id='lblReais' class='ph03_104' style='display: none'></span></div></td></tr>";
//echo $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio']; 
}
?>
```

A princípio, está tudo OK, mas se eu faço primeiro uma busca com check-in maior que 3 dias e depois faço outra com check-in menor que 3 dias, aí aparecem os *checkboxes*, porém, se eu repetir essa busca na sequência, aí já somem os checkbox (sendo que eles deveriam ter sumido na vez anterior). O mesmo acontece se a primeira busca é com check-in menor que 3 (não aparecem os checkboxes), faço uma segunda busca com check-in maior que 3 e aí não aparecem os checkboxes e, repetindo essa segunda busca, acabam aparecendo (quando deveriam ter aparecido na vez anterior).

Na linha comentada do código, decidi verificar como ela está vindo a variável `$_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio']`. Acho que ela demora pra atualizar, sendo que a atualização da página em novas busca costuma ser rápida.

Não sei se ficou muito clara a situação. O que eu poderia fazer nesse caso pra só vir os checkboxes na situação correta (data de check-in maior que 3 dias) e desaparecer na situação correta (data de check-in menor que 3 dias)?

Comment: Onde você declara a variavel $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio'] ??

Comment: depois do <?php tentou colocar o session_start Ex: **<?php session_start();**

Comment: Imagino que isso deveria ser resolvido no front-end, não? Com jquery ou javascript puro...

Comment: Não, javascript/jquery não são linguagem de servidor então elas não conseguem gerenciar as sessões

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer o uso de sessões no php você deve iniciar a sessão com o uso do session_start(), isso tanto na tela que coloca um valor na sessão como na tela que leia a mesma segue abaixo um exemplo.

> arquivo_setar_sessao.php

```
<?php
  session_start();//inicio a sessao
  $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio'] = "SUA DATA";
```

> arquivo_ler_sessao.php

```
<?php
  session_start();//inicio a sessao
  echo $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio']; //Vai imprimir SUA DATA
```

**Dica** [aqui no php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.session.php) você encontra manual de como fazer o uso das variáveis de sessão.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri a solução. Essa *session* recebe o valor de um *input* cujo id é `dtIni`. Usando de `$_REQUEST['dtIni']` no lugar da variável de *session* solucionou meu problema.

Comment: Gustavo, coloque sua resposta e depois marque ela como correta.