# Como setar e pegar objetos salvos na sessão em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo saber como faço para guardar um Array de objetos na sessão, e depois como recupera-los. Hoje utilizo o `sessionStorage.setItem("pessoa", arrayPessoa);` e `sessionStorage.getItem("pessoa");`, porem está dando *null* quando mando aparecer no console.

Como resolver isto ?

Comment: Tem uma pergunta semelhante aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72189/problema-com-vari%C3%A1vel-de-session, favor verificar se a resposta da mesma te ajuda.

Comment: @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas não tem nada haver session em php com sessionStorage em javascript

Comment: É @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas como o Gabriel falou, não tem nada haver.

Comment: Essa session vem de onde? PHP ou Java?

Comment: @GiancarloAbelGiulian na verdade eu faço uma pesquisa no IndexedDB e quero guarda as informações na sessão para poder acessa-las fora do onsuccess da função.

Comment: Tenta assim, request.getSession().getAttribute("pessoa"), request.getSession().setAttribute("pessoa", value), porem não sei se funciona com array...

Comment: So minuto para testar.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  deu este erro

Comment: Vale salientar que a programação é mobile

Comment: Você pode usar o sessionStorage mas tem que passa uma string para ele, ou seta os valores de Pessoa um por um, ou passa o array em forma de string

Comment: Faz uma resposta para mim observar como faz

Comment: Cara to dando um tiro no escuro, eu sou novato em programação, se não der não sei o que poderia dar certo, criei uma resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O sessionStorage não aceita diretamente um objeto porque ele é  criado por chave/valor, uma forma de inserir e depois ler um objeto é transforma-lo em string com a função JSON.stringify(), depois você pode pegar a session usando o sessionStorage.getItem() e dar um parse no valor, exemplo de como poderia ser implementado:

**Exemplo:**

```
 var b = {'nome': 'Gabriel', 'sobrenome': 'Rodrigues'};
 b = JSON.stringify(b);
 sessionStorage.setItem('chave', b);
 var c = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('chave'));
 console.info(c);
```

Veja funcionando no [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/78kww75y/)

Comment: O resultado foi este: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: da uma olhada no exemplo funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/78kww75y/

Comment: Se der "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" pra você, é porque o objeto que está salvo lá na sessionStorage não é o serializado, é o que você já tinha colocado antes.

Answer (score 1):

Se puder crie um JSON para o array da Pessoa:

```
{"Status":"OK!","Pessoa":
[{"IdPessoa":01,"Nome":"JOAO"},
 {"IdPessoa":02,"Nome":"MARIA"}
]}
```

Depois passe o JSON em forma de String:

```
var parsedResult = JSON.parse(result);
sessionStorage.setItem("Pessoa", JSON.stringify(parsedResult.Pessoa));
```

Neste caso `JSON.parse(result)`, result é um JSON dinâmico.

Comment: Esta foi a mesma resposta que eu coloquei...

Comment: @Gabriel Se for ver, foi no mesmo minuto, então digitamos praticamente ao mesmo tempo. minha 18:08:19, tua 18:08:37